# Android overridePendingTransition doesn't work

Tags: android, animation

I use this link 
http://savagelook.com/blog/android/swipes-or-flings-for-navigation-in-android to make animation and it's work to me when I lanch app on emultor with android 2.3.3. But when I lanch it on my phone(HTC wildfire with android 2.2 api level 8) the animation doesn't work. Activites are being changed without animation.
Any suggetion?